# How to make predictions in tensorflow ranking from saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, ranking

I'm using the following example of tensorflow ranking: [handling_sparse_features on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/handling_sparse_features.ipynb#scrollTo=b1QymoFfDNr7)

At the end it shows how predictions can be made using the ranker of the trained model. That works fine.

```
def predict_input_fn(path):
  context_feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(
        context_feature_columns().values())
  example_feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(
        list(example_feature_columns().values()))
  dataset = tfr.data.build_ranking_dataset(
        file_pattern=path,
        data_format=tfr.data.ELWC,
        batch_size=_BATCH_SIZE,
        list_size=_LIST_SIZE,
        context_feature_spec=context_feature_spec,
        example_feature_spec=example_feature_spec,
        reader=tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
        shuffle=False,
        num_epochs=1)
  features = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset).get_next()
  return features

predictions = ranker.predict(input_fn=lambda: predict_input_fn("/tmp/test.tfrecords"))

x = next(predictions)
```

How can I save and use the model (or the "ranker") so that I do not need always do the whole training step? I would like to save the ranker and then use it as above:

```
predictions = ranker.predict(input_fn=lambda: predict_input_fn("/tmp/test.tfrecords"))
```

I found these explanation: https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/issues/53
There they suggest the following:

```
feature_columns = example_feature_columns()
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
export_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
ranker.export_savedmodel("savedmodel", export_fn)
```

But this includes only the feature_spec of the examples. For my problem I need to input both, feature_spec of examples and context, something similar to predict_input_fn.